# weird Issue in using the page layout analysis of tesseract 3.01

Tags: c++, image-processing, orientation, ocr, tesseract

i'm using tesseract 3.01,i used the enum PageSegMode for page segmentation and orientation, when i used the attribute PSM_AUTO_OSD it detects the orientation of the page only when it's rotated 90 degree to the left otherwise it fails,can any one tell me what's the problem,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [tesseractmain.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/trunk/api/tesseractmain.cpp?r=554) its suposed to be `PSM_AUTO`:

```
tesseract::PageSegMode pagesegmode = tesseract::PSM_AUTO;
// ...

tesseract::TessBaseAPI  api;
api.SetPageSegMode(pagesegmode);
// ...
```

Try to reproduce your problem with the cmd-line tool, and give it `-psm 0` for orientation.